# RegularExpression for URL Rewriting

Tags: asp.net, regex, urlrewriter.net

I am using [urlrewriter.net](http://urlrewriter.net/) and I am trying to make a redirection. So here is the condition,

> If the requested url doesn't end with a **/** (slash) and
>   then add **/** at the end of the url and
>   redirect to added url.

So if the url is "http://www.something.com/cases" then add `/` and redirect it to "http://www.something.com/cases/"

I've used code but it didn't work out for me :

```
<if url="^~/(.+)(/){0}$">
    <redirect url="~/(.+)" to="~/$1/$"/>
</if>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to answer my own question here :

I've accomplished this by using this way :

```
<unless url="^(/.+(\.gif|\.png|\.jpg|\.ico|\.pdf|\.css|\.js|\.aspx|\.ashx|\.ascx|\.shtml|\.html|\.htm)(\?.+)?)$">
    <if url=".+(?&lt;!/)$">
        <redirect url="(.+)" to="$1/"/>
    </if>
</unless>
```

If url doesn't end with "/" then it will be redirected to the one which has "/" at the end.

I hope it helps everyone out there.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the URL Rewrite 2.0 module? You can easily add it there, because the rewrite template for that rule is a built-into the GUI.

Comment: Well, I am thinking to move forward to URL Rewrite 2.0 since Microsoft already supports in right inside of IIS.